# Работа с системами контроля версий в веб-программировании

Tags: веб-программирование, контроль-версий

Добрый день! У меня вопрос такой кто какую систему контроля версий использует в веб-программировании, где синхронизация изменений файлов или откат данных происходит с удаленного сервера. В моем случае часто приходится использоваться 1с-Битрикс систему для проектирования сайтов, и как написано в документации TortoiseHg подходит для этой задачи для управления проектом. Однако не совсем понятно как работает эта система контроля версий. Подскажите кто работал с этой системой, есть ли какая-то русская документация? И для тех кто работал с другими системами контроля версий, порекомендуйте может что хорошее, с учетом того что разрабатываются не программы, а сайты, хранящиеся как правило на удаленных серверах.

Answer (score 1):

[git](http://githowto.com/ru)? с меркури не работал... есть [цикл статей](http://habrahabr.ru/post/108658/) на хабре по меркуриалу

Comment: git умеет работать с веб-проектами, находящимися на удаленных серверах, и чтобы синхронизировать потом работу по ftp? А насчет Mercurial в него как раз и входит TortoiseHg. Сегодня буквально полчаса назад ее скачал и установил и пока не удалось разобраться как же синхронизировать (получать и отдавать данные) с удаленного веб-сайта....

Comment: @IntegralAL, "синхронизация по фтп" - это прошлый век. Гит умеет стягивать обновления по http и не только, для автоматического обновления предусмотрена система хуков.

Comment: Tortoise* это надстройки для винды. есть TortoiseGit, TortioseSVN еще... ftp -- прошлый век, как правильно замечено, есть система хуков. в идеале можно спокойно использовать CI тулы типа Jenkins/Hudson. Если не хочется, то есть мини скрипты по автодеплою, например вот: https://github.com/logsol/Github-Auto-Deploy   
у меня на паре серваков такое стоит, просто и удобно :)

Comment: @Fike, ну хорошо гит умеет стягивать по http. Расскажите тогда в каком виде стягиваются данные там? У меня например стоит 1с-Битрикс, мне нужно чтобы на локальную машину в хранилище заливалось полное содержимое сайта, которое можно было редактировать в форматах php, tpl и.т.д., а потом обратно отдавать на сервер изменения. Трудно представить что лишь по http это все возможно...или я плохо знаю возможности протокола http...

Comment: ну не только http, ssh еще есть :)   
хранится там все как файлы, редактируем, пушим, пуллим на целевом сервере. вопрос не понятен. картинки же вы в контактик заливаете по http. :)

Comment: > Расскажите тогда в каком виде стягиваются данные там?

    git init - выполняется один раз
    git remote add *имя* *источник* - выполняется один раз
    git pull

Все, на машине актуальная версия

> мне нужно чтобы на локальную машину в хранилище заливалось полное содержимое сайта, которое можно было редактировать в форматах php, tpl и.т.д., а потом обратно отдавать на сервер изменения.

1. Завести репу на битбакете/гитхабе
2. Залить туда текущую версию
3. Работать с ней на локалке
4. Настроить хук на обновление ветки, скажем, deploy, который заставит сервер стягивать обновления

Comment: 5. Обновлять ветку deploy каждый раз, когда нужно обновить сервак

> Трудно представить что лишь по http это все возможно...или я плохо знаю возможности протокола http...

Плохо представляете, что есть протокол HTTP. По HTTP можно передавать что угодно, это всего лишь оболочка.

Answer (score 0):

Какая VCS больше нравится такую и используйте. Главное используйте правильно: осильте разработать процедуру деплоя сайта, а не просто совмещать локальный репозиторий и DocumentRoot веб-сервера.